# How do I check if a name is in use in Excel using VSTO?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I need to know if a name is already in use in Excel (for example as a named range) so that I do not allow the attempted creation of duplicate names. I tried the following but the loop body never executes (there are no exceptions thrown, it just looks like the collection is empty).

Can anyone suggest and alternative?

```
foreach (Excel.Name n in _workbook.Names)
{
    if (n.Name == name) return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Are you sure that there are named ranges in this work book ?

Comment: The code works fine. Even for Sheet scoped names. As @Timores said, are you sure you have named ranges?

Comment: I definitely did. Anyway, I went about it a different way and resolved the problem.